# .NET Core Web Api: call localhost returns 404

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, localhost, asp.net-core-webapi

I've a **.NET Core Web Api** and when I start the project with IIS Express I get a 404, 
when I use Postman and call a web Api-localhost (without route) I get a 500.
But in my case I get a 404, with or without route.
At the launch.settings I got:

```js
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:63793",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
```

**Why I get a 404 when I call "http://localhost:63793"?**

Comment: What URL are you accessing? How does your controller look?

Comment: http://localhost:63793/graph/Users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that you have provided the controller, I belive you simply are accessing the wrong URL.

```
[Route("graph/[controller]")]
public class GraphController : ControllerBase
```

This means you should probably access `graph/graph/users`

The controller part here `["graph/[controller"]` will get the same name as your controller name, e.g **Graph**Controller. A simple elegant solution would be to rename the first part to `api/[controller]` --> then the url will be `baseurl:port/api/graph/route` or in your case: `localhost:63793/api/graph/users`

Try it out.

Comment: No problem, happy to help! :)

Answer (score 0):

> Why I get a 404 when I call "http://localhost:63793"?

It seems because you don't have a resource on this address.

> localhost:63793/graph/Users

According to your routes attributes `[Route("graph/[controller]")]` and `[Route("Users")]` your resource is located on `localhost:63793/graph/graph/users` since you have a prefix `graph/` and your controller is named `GraphController`. Usually api urls have `api/` prefix.